# How does transform-origin work with scale and transition?

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply transform-origin in order to transform an image downwards. If I apply the transform-origin with scale-only, I seem to get the expected result, that the image scales downwards:

```
transformOrigin: 50% 0%;
transform: scale(2);
```

But if I also translate the image, the transform origin seems to make the image scale more downwards, but also a littelbit upwards:

```
  transformOrigin: 50% 0%;
  transform: scale(2) translateY(20px);
```

Comment: I don't understand "more downwards, but also a littelbit upwards". Your wording seems contradictory.  It behaves as expected for me.

Comment: With your second sample, it first moves, then it scale (transform execute its commands right to left) ... so I guess that explains it, so to first scale then translateY, switch their order

Comment: @LGSon Maybe. I don't understand the question

Comment: @Oriol Since the `translateY` executes before `scale`, it moves down a little, then up again affected by the scale ... which I'm sure the _first downwards, then a little upwards_ mean :) ... opposed to not use `translateY`

Comment: _Himmators_ låter skånskt? ... eller en håla utanför storstan :)

Comment: Himmators allows Scanian? ... Or a den outside of the big city

Comment: @LGSon   ... odd ... 2 people from Sweden, 2 from Barcelona

Comment: @vals Yes :) ... and "Himmators låter skånskt? = Himmators sounds like _south-swedish_?"